# Cytoscape.js particle trail animation

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is anyone aware of a cytoscape.js plugin that allows one to animate a given graph to represent the rate of 'flow' between nodes? For example, anime.js allows to generate particle trails, which could use the nodes in a given graph as anchors that are interpolated by particle trails.
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/04/particle-trail-animation-javascript/

I have searched but not found a potential solution to this issue.